SSL Certificate error - API Jira Connect via Python
Thank you in advance for your suggestions and help. I am using following configurations for connecting Jira via API:
JIRA_LINK = "My Jira Link"
JIRA_TOKEN = 'My Token'

jira = JIRA(JIRA_LINK,token_auth=JIRA_TOKEN)

It keeps failing with following error:
Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))) WARNING:root:HTTPSConnectionPool(host='My Jira Link', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))
How do I validate the certificate?
I have tried searching it on stackoverflow and have also googled the error. However, did not find the way out to either bypass the certificate  validation or provide file path. There are ways mentioned however the way they have connected to Jira is different than what I have used.
I dont want to use python-certifi-win32
